# Getting phonetic data fields from Excel into Xcode

Tags: objective-c, excel, parsing

I have a large excel spreadsheet of Japanese words that have their phonetics shown as per example screenshot below - look at column B. The phonetic characters are the tiny characters above the Chinese characters.

I'm familiar with parsing CSV files in Xcode but when I save this spreadsheet as a CSV I lose the phonetic characters. Does anyone know a way I can get the excel file into a format that retains the phonetic characters and that I can still parse in Xcode?

[image]

Comment: When you export the CSV file from Excel, make sure you use UTF-8 file encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel doesn't support exporting furigana/ruby/phonetic text in plain text formats.

You'll either have to (1) use the [`PHONETIC`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/phonetic-function-HA102752905.aspx) function to extract the text into a separate column (which you seem to already have) and use that column, or (2) export the file to HTML and parse that (Excel will mark the text with `<ruby><rp><rt>` elements).

Comment: Thanks for the tip re export to HTML. Was simple as saving as a web page and then as per rmaddy's suggestion using UTF-8 encoding. Works nicely.